# How to change properties of elemnts\childs created with script on flash builder

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder, flex4.5

Hi guys im creating/adding elemnts in my item renderer but from some reason you cant access their specific properties, you can only change the general properties. I created a LABEL component but when i do LabelName.font , nothing happens, its like flex doesnt recognize that this is a LABEL. Here is my code

```
                var mylabel:Label = new Label()
                mylabel.font
```

when i do "mylabel.someProperty" it only shows the general properties of any component, but how can i change other properties like font,color,size etc..

Thanks ahead [=

Comment: Not really related but don't forget to add a ; character add the end of the first line ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fonts are defined as styles in Flex, not propeties, so you need to use the setStyle method to update it. (Not my favorite part about Flex.) For example:

```
myLabel.setStyle('fontFamily', newFont)
```

Comment: thanks alot! this is done only for style properties , other properites are referenced through componenetName.property right?

Comment: that's right. It really is too bad that styles are only code completed in mxml.

Comment: just one more thing, im asking this, because what i used to do is create all the components that i might need (10 label and 2 datagroup) and then removed the ones i dont need through "RemoveElement", do you think that ill see a much better runtime now after creating only the elements i need? , theres not much information about flex considering UIcomponents. Ihave many conflicts when creating UI in terms of whats is more efficent \:

Comment: @user1108310 It's certainly more efficient to only create the components that you will actually need. To know how much, you would need test your particular usecase. However, I would absolutely avoid adding the components to the display list as that would definitely be a large overhead.

Comment: I didnt really get the last part,what do you mean avoid adding the components to the display list? out of the 10 labels and 2 datagroup i usually need 1 data group and 4 labels. What i was planning on doing is first make some checks, and than add only the elemnts i need through ActionScript, insteadd of creating 10 labels and 2 datagroup in MXML as before. Is that the right way of doing it?

Comment: and one more thing! im not able to add myButton.click . Is there anyway to deterimne this functionality? Thanks again

Comment: What you're planning on doing sounds correct. And for the click event `myButton.addEventListener(Event.CLICK, function);`

Comment: Thanks Thanks Thanks, you really saved me alot of time and headache [=

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between MXML and ActionScript in this. In MXML, styles of a component are shown as if they were properties, when they are really not. To set the fontFamily of your label in AS3 code, for example, you would use

```
myLabel.setStyle("fontFamily", "Arial")
```